# Datetime display using month name in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a field which is date type in a table. The format of this field is mm/dd/yy. Is there any way to convert it to dd-Month name-yy?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without any hassle, you can use [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(SQL.90).aspx) to get "dd MONTHNAME yyyy" format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 106)
```

e.g. "25 Jan 2010"

If you want your exact format, you may need a bit of manual fiddling around like:

```
SELECT CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) +  '-' + LEFT(DATENAME(mm, GETDATE()), 3) + '-' + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR), 2)
```

e.g. "25-Jan-10"

**Update:**
In fact, a shorter way to achieving this is:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 6), ' ', '-')
```

e.g. "25-Jan-10"

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `CAST` and `CONVERT` functions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 2):

example:

```
select convert( char(8), getdate(), 5 )
```

output:

dd-mm-yy

[Source: compuspec date format conversion](http://www.compuspec.net/reference/database/sybase/function/convert.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

you can try [convert()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to differentiate between storing datetime values in SQL Server and displaying them. Here is a great article that explains what's going on behind the scenes: [The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp)